# Display high-DPI image at 50% scaling using just CSS

Tags: html, css, image, retina-display, dpi

Our app is fetching and displaying images from third parties. We don't know what the image size is, but we can control the DPI, so we can request double-DPI images for high resolution screens.

My question is: is there an HTML+CSS solution that can render a given image at double resolution? Doing something like:

```
img.hidpi {
    width: 50%;
}
```

doesn't work because `50%` isn't calculated on the content of the image.

Some kinds of JS are ok, but I'd prefer not to have to use JavaScript to inspect the content of the image - our codebase makes that quite tricky.

Comment: If you need the image to fit and scale within a container the `object-fit` property might help. Try setting `object-fit: cover;` on the img.

Comment: @Danield no, he just wants to scale an `<img>` to 50% of its natural height and width, nothing to do with containers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Setting `width` and `height`

As far as I know there is no way to get the dimensions of an image with CSS. With JavaScript you can do the following:

```
var myImgs = document.getElementsByClassName('hidpi');
for (var i = 0; i < myImgs.length; i++) {
  var width = myImgs[i].naturalWidth,
      height = myImgs[i].naturalHeight;

  myImgs[i].width = width / 2;
  myImgs[i].height = height / 2;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6onq64fr/) for this version.

#### CSS3 `scale()`

You could use css3 `transform`, but this has the disadvantage that it keeps consuming the whole (not transformed) space:

```css
.hidpi {
  transform: scale(.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w75qjkpn/).

Comment: That latter answer looks good - what do you mean about consuming the whole space though? You mean that other objects to the right or below it will act as though it was still its full size?

Comment: Exactly. `transform` does not change an element's layout but only controls the rendering.